# is there a way to find a specific text and highlight it

Tags: selenium

I am trying to search the text and highlight it, but it give me a error no such element: Unable to locate.

I am using boolean then I found the text but i don't know how to highlight it in a selenium.

```
myD.getPageSource().contains("Power of Selenium WebDriver with ");
boolean Error = myD.getPageSource().contains("frequent test steps as KEYWORDS");

        if (Error == true)
        {
         System.out.print("Text Found");

        //   highLightElement();

        }
        else
        {
         System.out.print("Text not Found");
        }
```

Other thing, I use WebElement but it give me error no such element found

```
    driver.get("https://anyaut.com/");
    WebElement matchedElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'frequent test steps as KEYWORDS')]"));
    highLightElement(matchedElement);
```

**HighlightElement:**

```
public static void highLightElement(WebElement element){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;   
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);   
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how you are planning to highlight an element that can't be found? It sounds like your locator is bad and you need to fix it. We can't help with that because you haven't provided a link to the page or relevant HTML.

Comment: Here is the link https://anyaut.com/

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: [link](https://anyaut.com/)  and also reference in the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Looking into https://anyaut.com/ website there is the following construction:

```
<p class="green-border-inner-content">Built using <font color="#34d293">Page Object, Data Driven &amp; Keyword Driven
    Automation Frameworks</font>. Has the facility to group frequent test steps as KEYWORDS , along with reusable Test
    Data and Element Identifiers.</p>
```

It means that there are 2 text [nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp) and your expression is taking into consideration only first one, to wit `Built using`

In order to extract the `frequent test steps as KEYWORDS` text you need to provide the [`position` predicate](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
//p[contains(text()[2],'frequent test steps as KEYWORDS')]
```

Or if you want to go for the [wildcard](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_wildcard.htm) you need to amend your expression to look like:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'frequent test steps as KEYWORDS')]]
```

[image]